# Optimizing a Google card layout

Tags: android, xml, layout

I'm developing an Android app in which I would build a card layout with a custom library. I think that my layout has not been optimized, but I don't know how I can this. It's not a very simple layout for me, but I'm new to this and I can't make better.

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="110dp">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:orientation="vertical">

            <RelativeLayout
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content">

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/LVdate"
                    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
                    android:textStyle="bold"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/LVtask"
                    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_below="@+id/LVdate"
                    android:textStyle="italic"/>

            </RelativeLayout>

            <RelativeLayout
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="8dp">

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/LVtxtWorkingH"
                    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="@string/TotalHours"/>

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/LVWorkingh"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/LVtxtWorkingH"
                    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/LVtxtWorkingH"
                    android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/LVtxtWorkingH"/>

            </RelativeLayout>

            <RelativeLayout
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content">

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/LVtxtOvertime"
                    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="@string/OverTime"/>

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/LVovertime"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/LVtxtOvertime"
                    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/LVtxtOvertime"
                    android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/LVtxtOvertime"/>

            </RelativeLayout>

            <RelativeLayout
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginBottom="8dp">

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/LVtxtTotalPayDay"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="@string/PayToday"/>

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/LVTotalPayDay"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/LVtxtTotalPayDay"
                    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/LVtxtTotalPayDay"
                    android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/LVtxtTotalPayDay"/>

            </RelativeLayout>

    </LinearLayout>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
        android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp">

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/btnDeleteWD"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_action_discard"
            android:layout_marginBottom="18dp"
            android:background="@color/white"/>

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/btnEditWD"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
            android:background="@color/white"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_action_edit"
            android:layout_marginTop="18dp"
            android:layout_below="@+id/btnDeleteWD"/>

    </RelativeLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Aah! You're using way too many layouts than you need.

You're using `leftOf` and `rightOf` attribute of `RelativeLayout` but you are ignoring power `top` and `below` attributes.

You can use them and get rid of all middle layer `RelativeLayouts` and eventually once you fix that, you can also get rid of first `LinearLayout` as it's just wrapping the `RelativeLayout`

So your final layout hierarchy may look like this --> `LinearLayout`  with two `RelativeLayouts`

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
          xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
          android:orientation="horizontal"
          android:layout_width="match_parent"
          android:layout_height="110dp">

<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="8dp">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/LVdate"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        tools:text="LVDate"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/LVtask"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        tools:text="LVtask"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/LVdate"
        android:textStyle="italic"/>

    <TextView
        android:layout_below="@id/LVtask"
        android:id="@+id/LVtxtWorkingH"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="TotalHours"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/LVWorkingh"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        tools:text="LVWorkingh"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/LVtxtWorkingH"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/LVtxtWorkingH"
        android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/LVtxtWorkingH"/>

    <TextView
        android:layout_below="@id/LVtxtWorkingH"
        android:id="@+id/LVtxtOvertime"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="OverTime"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/LVovertime"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        tools:text="LVovertime"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/LVtxtOvertime"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/LVtxtOvertime"
        android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/LVtxtOvertime"/>

    <TextView
        android:layout_below="@id/LVtxtOvertime"
        android:id="@+id/LVtxtTotalPayDay"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="PayToday"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/LVTotalPayDay"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        tools:text="LVTotalPayDay"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/LVtxtTotalPayDay"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/LVtxtTotalPayDay"
        android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/LVtxtTotalPayDay"/>

</RelativeLayout>

<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
    android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="8dp">

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/btnDeleteWD"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:src="@android:drawable/ic_menu_delete"
        android:layout_marginBottom="18dp"
        android:background="#FFF"/>

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/btnEditWD"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:background="#FFF"
        android:src="@android:drawable/ic_menu_delete"
        android:layout_marginTop="18dp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/btnDeleteWD"/>

</RelativeLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

I hope this helps! :)

`RelativeLayout` is very powerful. You can also get rid of another `RelativeLayout` for `buttons` and use relative measurement to layout everything in just on `RelativeLayout`, but that might look little bit messy.